# Batch Delete Attributes?

Tags: attributes

Our store has thousands of color attributes and we want to clean out the ones that are old, inactive, or unused. Is there a solution for this? Is there an easy way to see what attributes aren't currently being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way which does not include some database poking.
If you are ok with using sql queries, then you can do

```
SELECT `attribute_id` FROM `eav_attribute` ea WHERE ea.`entity_type_id`=4 
AND `attribute_id` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `attribute_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity_int`)
AND `attribute_id` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `attribute_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` )
AND `attribute_id` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `attribute_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` )
AND `attribute_id` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `attribute_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` )
AND `attribute_id` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `attribute_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity_gallery` )
AND `attribute_id` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `attribute_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` )
AND `attribute_id` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `attribute_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity_datetime` )
```

The above will give you unused attributes, however you should not try to directly delete them from database.